# Unity chat dialog system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialog

I am trying to make a chat dialogue in unity which should show up when colliding with an object and press a key. The chat dialogue should remain until collision exit. The issue is that the chat dialogue shows up on key press when in collision but turns false in the same second so it flickers. the bool is being reset instead of remaining true while in collision.

```
        hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 5f);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < hitColliders.Length) {

        if (hitColliders [i].gameObject.tag == "gameobjectCollision") { 

            if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.F)) {
                Debug.Log ("pressed F");
                DialogueController.showConversation = true;

            } 

            break;
        } 

        else {

            Debug.Log ("Conversation Off");
            DialogueController.showConversation = false;
        }

        i++;
  }
```

Also, script is being attached properly and mesh collider is set with colliding game object. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should really think about doing this off of triggers and not collision. So making a separate trigger box for each NPC that you can talk to in your game. And then make use of OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit in your player script. OnTriggerEnter you can allow the conversation to start by a button click, and then OnTriggerExit you can turn off the coversation.

```
public void Update()
{
   if (inInteractRange && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
   {
      DialogueSystemManager.Instance.StartDialogueForNpc(interactableNPCName);
   }
}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
   inInteractRange = true;
}
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
{
   inInteractRange = false;
   DialogueSystemManager.Instance.CloseDialogueWindow();
}
```

Comment: I actually tried with triggers but the collisions were sort of buggy, sometimes the dialog opens sometimes nothing happens. With the current method the update is checking for collisions every frame

Comment: Yea that gets really really expensive on the system. But If you are going to do collision based detection for a dialogue system you should really plug into unity's OnCollisionEnter and OnCollisionExit event. And just toggle a Boolean inside of that callback method. 

But I have a dialogue manager system up in the unity asset store that uses triggers and no one has had any issues with the trigger system. And only reason I suggest using triggers is they are way less expensive on the system when you have lots of objects your game is monitoring. I have updated my answer to show the code I use

Comment: Change the OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit to OnCollisionEnter and OnCollisionExit if you want to use collision events instead of triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

1. Generate an event from OnTriggerEnter.
2. Create an ChatDialogueHandler Script and an add listener to that event.
3. Enable the chat dialogue box when event is raised and disable the chat dialogue box after some specific time.